# Will the instance class release if the member class still contain strong references?

Tags: objective-c

Let say my instance (`instA`) has a property called `(strong) NSString *text`.

and I want to get the value of another (`instB`) instance's text `(strong) NSString *name`.

```
instA.text = instB.name.
```

If `instB`'s reference count goes to zero, will `instA.text` be `nil`-ed? And can `instB` even be released because one of it's members's reference count isn't zero yet?

Comment: You should generally be using `copy` when declaring a property of type `NSString`, `NSArray`, or `NSSet` because they each have mutable subclasses. You typically don't want the string/array/set being modified out from under you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, `instA.text = instB.name` adds a reference to the string on `instA`'s behalf, so it won't be released until `instA` is released.
2. No, it doesn't go in the other direction. Retaining `instB`'s member doesn't retain `instB` itself.

More information is available in [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), or for Swift, in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).